# Triangle with one colored edge in Java

Tags: java, graphics, 3d

I`m new to graphics in Java. What I am looking for is direction and guidance on what approach I need to take. I need to draw a triangle with one different colored edge, like the one shown in the picture. I need to draw a few hundred thousand of these connected to each other to make a ribbon. What is the most efficient way to do this? Code examples are appreciated.

[image: Triangle with one colored edge]

Comment: You need to show what you have tried and why it is not working! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I haven`t tried anything yet, what I am looking for is a direction to proceed in.

Comment: Asking for code *"Code examples are appreciated."*  when you have done nothing is **extremely off-topic**. Please read the ["Help > On Topic"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["How to Ask"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you do not understand why this is not on topic.